# jQuery Make Div scroll vertically with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side-menu that I have set to have position as sticky. I have a div next to it that I want to go up and down along with the scrollbar. As scrollbar is moved, it should move according to height(vertically).

An example of this scrolling functionality can be found at the dropbox.com website in the "File storage and sharing" section.

This is my starting code. I believe this can be achieved using Javascript and Css transforms but I was unable to find the resources on the internet.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/zestweb/pen/BayexWa

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="nav">
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
    <p>Nav Item</p>
  </div>

  <div class="scrollbar-container">
            <div id="custom-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 3000px;
}

.nav {
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.scrollbar-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    z-index: 50;
}
#custom-scrollbar {
    width: 2px;
    height: 95px;
    background: #ff8256;
    z-index: 1000;
    webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following jquery code

```js
function scrollMenu(){

  document.getElementById('menu').scrollIntoView({
      block: "end", behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

```css
#menu {
  height: 500px;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
<button onClick=scrollMenu()>Scroll</button>
</div>
```

To see the behavoir of **scrollIntoView** you can visit the following URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView